# how to have columns from other tables without doing a join in sql

Tags: java, sql

I've done some pretty basic stuff in sql with all the select, insert, delete stuff so I am not an expert...right now I am working on a java persistence,primefaces etc...and I have a tables called `assets` and `location`. The question I have is I want to have a table called `reports` that's gonna have `assets` and `location`columns in it, is there anyway I could have columns from `assets` and `location` in a table reports without doing a join ? I am trying to make it easier on my programming isues...

I want to create a table `reports` like this but without doing a join

```
assets_id
assets_name
location_id
location_name
etc
```

edit:

I want to create a table, not select sorry I should've said it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have M assets and N locations, unless you want a table with M*N rows, which is probably not what you want (and if it is then I'd suggest reviewing "what you want"), you'll need to do a join.

However, you can use a view, which is essentially a canned select statement, to make subsequent queries easier to write:

```
create view reports as
  select foo.x, bar.y from foo, bar where foo.id = bar.id
```

and then (for select purposes) you can treat reports as if it were a table.

Comment: so you are saying I could create a table like this using view ???..I've never used view before...this would be something I would totally I want

Comment: From a querying point of view you can treat "reports" as a table, e.g. "select * from reports", but it isn't a real table. It doesn't physically exist (i.e. if you query it then the underlying query from the view definition will be executed), there are constraints on how you can update it etc. However, it's useful for (a) making queries simpler, and (b) providing a consistent interface to clients - you can change the actual tables but create a backwards-compatibility view that looks like the old tables. See e.g. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html for more info.

Comment: thank you!...I appreciate the time you took...I am using sql server, I am gonna go with something like this...for others to see http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server/Creating_a_View_with_Data_from_Multiple_Tables.html

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
SELECT assets_id, assets_name, location_id, location_name INTO reports FROM assets, location;
```